# Java stream - apply two filters and collect to two collections in one iteration

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I have a map to iterate, and I want to check the values of entryset with two conditions; if meet condition 1, I group it into a collection, `findFirst()` and get the `Optional<>`, if not, filter with another condition and collect to another collection, do the same.

I did with `for` loops in one iteration. Now, if I want to iterate only once with Java 8 stream, is it possible?

I have tried with `stream().filter(cond1).map(Map.Entry::getValue).findFirst()` (iterate twice).

I also checked `groupingBy()` and `partitionBy()` but I haven't seen the possibility yet.

---

Example of approach 1:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Response> entry: responses.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Response value = entry.getValue();
    if (key.equals("foo") && !value.equals("bar")) {
        res1 = value;
    } else if (key.equals("some other key")) {
        res2 = value;
    }
}

Response finalResponse = res1 != null ? res1 : res2;
```

Example of approach 2:

```
Optional<Response> res1 = Optional.empty();
Response res2;

res1 = responses.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("foo") && 
                !entry.getValue().equals("bar"))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .findFirst();
res2 = responses.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("some other key"))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .findFirst().orElse(null);

Response finalResponse = res1.orElse(res2);
```

Comment: if or else .. use `partitioningBy` possibly.

Comment: Haha well, trying to further my understanding of Java Stream here..

Comment: @Naman: `paritioningBy`? How it can be useful here? Would you provide a code? I tried but it was too clumsy.

Comment: @Nikolas I initially thought that the question read conditions as if/else, that is where partitioning would have been useful. But in the current context, the conditions are independent and hence doesn't make much sense to use `partitioningBy`. Though the question isn't really clear in terms of why one has to iterate through the entry set here. `containsKey`, `get` could have provided sufficient information imho.

Comment: An instance of `Response` can never be equal to the string `"bar"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your condition is just based on `.equals()` on a key and value, like you are showing in your question, you can just use `map.get()` and a simple `if` statement:

```
Response result = responses.get("foo");
if (result == null || result.equals(bar))
    result = responses.get("some other key");
```

So there is no need to use anything else.

Or as Holger suggested you may alternatively use `map.getOrDefault()`:

```
Response result = responses.getOrDefault("foo", bar); 
if(result.equals(bar))
    result = responses.get("some other key");
```

Comment: Alternatively, you may use `Response result = responses.getOrDefault("foo", bar); if(result.equals(bar)) result = responses.get("some other key");`

Comment: @Holger Yes, that is a great alternative. Thanks for suggesting this.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you need using [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```
Response response = Optional
        .ofNullable(responses.get("foo"))              // find the "foo" Response
        .filter(value -> !"bar".equals(value)) // except if is null or "bar"
        .orElse(responses.get("other"));    // then find the "other" response (then null)
```

---

Few insights:

1. Having the code:

   ```
   if (key.equals("foo") && !value.equals("bar")) {
       res1 = value;
   } else if (key.equals("some other key")) {
       res2 = value;
   }
   ```

   Inside the loop unnecessarily checks for both conditions with each iteration although each key may occur only *once*. Consider the `break` usage in case the `res1` and `res2` are set.
2. The [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) is not a win here. Notice the `entry.getKey().equals("foo")` shall be shortened to `map.get("foo")` which returns `null` in case the key is not present. That's why I used this behavior with the [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: `ofNullable(responses.get("foo"))` for the absence of the key `foo`.

Comment: Yes, you are right :)